# How to expand a widget with scroll in Flutter

Tags: flutter, scrollview

[image: widget movemont]

I want to make a widget like attached photo.

According to my search, I have to use CustomScrollView, SliverAppBar.

I think this widget have to be ahead of background widget. so, have i to use a Stack widget?
In this case, i have an overflow problem when the widget shown on the screen is only a small size, what should I do about this?

Searching Result:
https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This : [DraggableScrollableSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html)

```
DraggableScrollableSheet(
                      initialChildSize: 0.2,
                      minChildSize: 0.2,
                      maxChildSize: 1.5,
                      expand: false,
                      builder: (_, controller) => ,
                  ),
```

Comment: I found a good package as an additional search about your information. Thank you.

https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel